# AWS Lambda Log Output Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, logging, aws-lambda

Hello I am testing out AWS Lambda and I keep getting the boilerplate output in my logs. I am new to AWS and this might be an easy fix but I have not been able to find a solution even in the docs.

Here is my index.js file

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Different OutPut'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

And here is the log output in the lambda console:

```
Response:
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"Hello from Lambda!\""
}

Request ID:
"dc746181-ec98-4c8a-8e09-c6157da669cb"
```

I am expecting to have 'Different OutPut' as the body.

Also here are the role permissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you keep getting `Hello from Lambda!` then it probably means that you **haven't deployed** the function before you test/execute it.

You have to **explicitly deploy** (orange `Deploy` button) function after each change in the code, so that changes take effect.

The other possibility is that you are executing wrong/old version of your function. In this case you have to explicitly select correct version if you have created any versions of your function.

Comment: Hi this worked! I had to hit deploy after saving the file thank you

Comment: @justinviola no problem. If the answer was helpful it's acceptance would be appreciated.